# Backbone Views listening to collection events is firing multiple times

Tags: backbone.js

I'm facing a very weird problem using ListenTo on subviews.

Basically I've a main view that contains multiple subviews.
Those subviews are initialized when their parent view is also initialized.
Some of those subviews are listening to the same global collection.

One of those views is a form that allow me to insert new entries into the collection
The second one is a list of all those entries contained into the collection.

So, basically it looks like this

```
$('button').on('click'.... 
   app.views.MyMainView = new MyMainView()
   //launch new modal window
   //with html body = app.views.MyMainView.el

var MyMainView = Backbone.view.extend({
     initialize: function(){
          // new Form_View()
          // new List_View()
     }
});

var Form_View = Backbone.view.extend({
      //get input value
      // create new entrie into the collection
});

var List_View = Backbone.view.extend({
     initialize: function(){
          // listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne)
          // new List_View()
          this.addAll();
     },
     addAll: function(){...},
     addOne: function(model){ .... }
});
```

The problem is the following:
When the user launch the modal for the first time and we add a new entry to the collection 
the listenTo add on the List_View fires as expected.

If I close the modal and the user clicks on 'button' to launch the modal window once again if I add a new entrie the view will fire 2 times the function that is listening to the collection add event.

If i close the modal again and re-open it the function will fire 3 times and so on.

This is weird because I'm creating a new instance of the view and their subviews everytime the user clicks on the 'button'. That's why it doesn't make sense to me.

Any help?

**EDIT**
    I also checked my collection by listening to the 'add' event inside of it.

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      this.listenTo( this, 'add', doSomething );
    },
    doSomething: function( model ){
        //do something fires as it should be firing the event: 1 time per each item inserted
    }
})
```

**EDIT 2**

```
var MyMainView = Backbone.View.extend({
.....    
close_modal: function(e){

                if(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                var viewsLen = this.views.length,
                    _that = this;

                _.each(this.views, function(view, key){

                    view.remove();

                    if(key + 1 == viewsLen )
                        _that.dialog.close();
                })

            }
...
})
```

**EDIT 3: 
ALL CODE**

//initialize modal 
$('button').on('click', function(){
     app.views.storePayment_View = new StorePayment_View(); 
})

```
var TMPL_StorePayment = '<div class="store-payment">'
                                + '<div class="store-payment-header">'
                                    + '<div class="client"></div>'
                                    + '<div class="status"></div>'
                                + '</div>'
                                + '<div class="payment-form"></div>'
                                + '<div class="payment-list"></div>'
                                + '<div class="x-form-actions">'
                                + '</div>'
                            + '</div>';


    var StorePayment_View = Backbone.View.extend({
        views: {},
        wrappers: {},
        collections: {},
        events: {
            "click .back": "close_modal",
            "click .finish-payment": "finish_payment"
        },
        initialize: function(){
            var _that = this;
            this.dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
                title: appLang["h67"],
                message: this.$el,
                closable: true,
                onhide: function(dialogRef){
                    _that.remove();
                }
            });

            this.dialog.realize();
            this.dialog.getModalFooter().hide();
            this.dialog.open();


            this.$el.html('').append( TMPL_StorePayment );
            this.wrappers.$client = this.$el.find('.client');
            this.wrappers.$status = this.$el.find('.status');
            this.wrappers.$payment_form = this.$el.find('.payment-form');
            this.wrappers.$payment_list = this.$el.find('.payment-list');
            this.wrappers.$form_actions = this.$el.find('.x-form-actions');
            this.render()
        },
        render: function(){



            this.views.StorePaymentForm_View = new StorePaymentForm_View();
            this.wrappers.$payment_form.html('').append( this.views.StorePaymentForm_View.el  );

            this.views.StorePaymentList_View = new StorePaymentList_View();
            this.wrappers.$payment_list.html('').append( this.views.StorePaymentList_View.el  );



        },
        close_modal: function(e){

            if(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            var viewsLen = this.views.length,
                _that = this;

            _.each(this.views, function(view, key){

                view.remove();

                if(key + 1 == viewsLen ){
                    _that.dialog.close();
                }

            })

        }

    })



    var StorePaymentForm_View = Backbone.View.extend({
        error_tmpl: _.template('<div class="alert alert-warning"><%= message %></div>') ,
        template: _.template('<div> <div class="input-field"> <input type="text" class="montant form-control" value="<%= restant %>"> </div> <div class="input-select"> <select name="payment-type"><% _.each(paymentTypeList, function(paymentType){ %>  <option value="<%= paymentType.typeMode %>"><%= paymentType.libelle %></option> <% }) %></select> </div> <div class="actions"><a href="#" class="add-new">Add new</a><a href="#" class="remove-all">Remove All</a> </div></div><div class="error_placeholder"></div>'),
        events:{
            "click .add-new": "add_new",
            "click .remove-all": "remove_all"
        },
        initialize: function(){
            this.collection = app.collections.StorePaymentList;

            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.render )
            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'destroy', this.render )
            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'change', this.render )
            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render )
            this.render()
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log("RENDER FIRED ON STOREPAYMENTFORM")
            var restant = this.collection.getRestant();
            if ( restant <= 0){
                restant = 0;
            }
            this.$el.html('').append( this.template( { "restant" : restant, "paymentTypeList": app.collections.PaymentTypeList.toJSON() } ) )

            var _that = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                _that.$el.find('select').selectBoxIt({
                    native: true,
                    autoWidth: false
                })

                _that.$el.find('input').focus();
            }, 50 )
        },
        add_new: function(e){

            console.log("add_new");

            if(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            var _that = this,
                input_val = this.$el.find('input').val(),
                select_val = this.$el.find('select :selected').val(),
                libelle = this.$el.find('select :selected').text(),
                wasNaN = false;


                input_val = parseInt(input_val);
                if (isNaN(input_val)){
                    wasNaN = true;
                    input_val = 0;
                }

                if (wasNaN){
                    _that.$el.find('.error_placeholder').html( _that.error_tmpl( { "message": appLang["h69"] } ) );     
                } else {
                    if ( input_val <= 0 ){
                        _that.$el.find('.error_placeholder').html( _that.error_tmpl( { "message": appLang["h70"] } ) );     
                    } else {
                        this.collection.add( new StorePaymentModel( { "libelle": libelle , "paymentId": select_val, "montant": input_val  } ) ) 
                    }   
                }
        },
        remove_all: function(e){
            if(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            var _that = this;
            //dialog are you sure?
            var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
                title: "Do you want to continue",
                message: "Do you really want to empty your current list of payments?",
                buttons: [{
                        label: appLang["a187"], //cancel
                        action: function(dialog) {

                            dialog.close();
                        }
                    }, {
                        label: appLang["a1621"], //ok
                        cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                        action: function(dialog) {
                            _that.collection.reset([]);
                            dialog.close();
                        }
                }]
            })

            dialog.realize();
            dialog.open();
        }
    })


    var StorePaymentListItem_View = Backbone.View.extend({
        events:{
            "click .remove": "remove_item",
            "click .save": "save"
        },
        template: _.template( '<%= libelle %> <%= montant %>  <a href="#" class="remove pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>' ),
        tagName: 'li',
        className: 'list-group-item',
        initialize: function(){
            this.render()
            //console.log("StorePaymentListItem_View initialized")
            this.listenTo( this.model, 'hide', this.remove )
        },
        render: function(){

            this.$el.html('').append( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) )

        },
        edit: function(){
            this.render_edit();
        },
        save: function(e){
            if (e){
                e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
            }
            this.render();
        },
        remove_item: function(e){
            if (e){
                e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
            }

            this.model.destroy();
        }
    })

    var StorePaymentList_View = Backbone.View.extend({
        $wrapper: $('<ul />', {'class': 'list-group' }),
        initialize: function(){
            this.$el.html('');
            this.collection = app.collections.StorePaymentList;

            this.listenTo( this.collection , 'add', this.addOne );
            this.listenTo( this.collection , 'change', this.render );
            this.listenTo( this.collection , 'reset', this.render );
            this.render()

        },
        render: function(){
            var totalItems = this.collection.length;
                this.$wrapper.html('')

            if (totalItems == 0){
                this.appendToRoot();
            } else {
                this.addAll()
            }    
        },
        addAll:function(){
            var _that = this,
                totalItems = this.collection.length;

            this.collection.forEach(function(model, key){
                _that.addOne(model)

                if (totalItems == key + 1)
                    _that.appendToRoot();
            })  
        },
        addOne:function( model ){

            var storePaymentListItem_View = new  StorePaymentListItem_View({ model: model });

            this.$wrapper.append( storePaymentListItem_View.el );

        },
        appendToRoot:function(){
            this.$el.html('').append( this.$wrapper );
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is closing the modal doesn't call `view.remove`, and so we end up with a zombie view that is removed from the DOM but still lives in memory listening to events.

Another guess is you never remove the List_View instance, so they are the zombies.

In other words, this is likely to be related to insufficient garbage collection.

This is a guess - it's impossible to tell without seeing the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: It could be that, but before calling the modal.close() i ensure that each subview is removed. Check my update.

Comment: This is not enough code to see the whole flow (what is `this.views` and when is `close_modal` being invoked, if I had to debug this, I'll add a log statement in the `initialize` methods and the `remove` methods and seek for parity

Comment: Also, it looks like `MyMainView` is the modal, and not `List_View`

Comment: Shouldn't close_modal remove the whole view?

Comment: And it does. But because I was starting to get frustrated I decided to ensure that all the views would be removed on close_modal by creating a loop function over subviews to remove them. If you take a look at this.dialog declaration you will see that there's a onhide function that removes the top level view after all the subviews get removed.

Comment: I am a little confused about the order of the flow. I would override the `remove` method of the master view and remove all children before removing itself, and then close the modal. I am not sure what is being triggered and in which order. I also don't know what onhide does - are you sure all the view.remove are actually being called?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49854/discussion-between-lothre1-and-uzi-kilon)